# How to override Bootstrap CSS without using inline styling?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to override Bootstrap's CSS of the following p element:
https://gyazo.com/6bf5dde284fa53fd4c9cd098ddb1f109

(I'd like to add a `top-margin: 10px;` and remove Bootstrap's bottom margin)

The only way I could get it to override thus far is to use inline styling which i'd prefer to avoid. Also I'd like to avoid `!important` unless really necessary.

My css files are ordered as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css">
```

Things i've tried:

```
<p id="pMargin">
#pMargin {
   margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

<p class="pMargin">
.pMargin {
   margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

#sdntLogForm p {
   margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

body p {
   margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!-- STUDENT TAB -->
<div id="student" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <form id="sdntLogForm" class="form-container" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="error">
      <?php
        if(isset($error)){
          echo ($error);
        }
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h1 class="formHeader">Student Login</h1>
      <label for="sdntLogEmail">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="sdntLogEmail" name="sdntLogEmail" placeholder="Email" tabindex="1" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sdntLogPass">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="sdntLogPass" name="sdntLogPass" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" id="sdntLogRemember" name="sdntLogRemember">Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="sdntLogSubmit" name="sdntLogSubmit" tabindex="4">Login</button>
    <p>If you don't have a student account, you can register one <a href="sdntRegister.php">here</a>.</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link opens a blank page here, so it's a bit hard to tell, but since you only have one p tag in that HTML code, I try it:

Use a CSS selector with as much specifity as possible, i.e.:

```
div#student.tab-pane.fade.in.active form#sdntLogForm.form-container p { ... }
```

Comment: The gyazo link is blank? It works for me, can I embed the image into the question some how? I'll give that a go, thanks

Comment: That worked, thanks very much. So just to confirm, the error was simply just the path not being specific enough? Or was I targeting the wrong element?

Comment: Yes, apparently there are combined selectors in your default CSS which are more specific than what you used before.